# Comparing dates ignoring the seconds and the milliseconds instant of DateTime in Joda

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, date-comparison

Let's assume that I have two dates like the following.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
DateTime firstDate = formatter.parseDateTime("16-Feb-2012 12:03:45");
DateTime secondDate = formatter.parseDateTime("17-Feb-2013 12:03:45");
```

I want to compare these two dates to see whether `firstDate` is sooner, later or equal to `secondDate`.

I could try the following.

```
System.out.println("firstDate = "+firstDate+"\nsecondDate = "+secondDate+"\ncomparison = "+firstDate.isBefore(secondDate));
System.out.println("firstDate = "+firstDate+"\nsecondDate = "+secondDate+"\ncomparison = "+firstDate.isAfter(secondDate));
System.out.println("firstDate = "+firstDate+"\nsecondDate = "+secondDate+"\ncomparison = "+firstDate.equals(secondDate));
```

What is produced by this code is exactly what I want.

It produces the following output.

```
firstDate = 2012-02-16T12:03:45.000+05:30
secondDate = 2013-02-17T12:03:45.000+05:30
comparison = true

firstDate = 2012-02-16T12:03:45.000+05:30
secondDate = 2013-02-17T12:03:45.000+05:30
comparison = false

firstDate = 2012-02-16T12:03:45.000+05:30
secondDate = 2013-02-17T12:03:45.000+05:30
comparison = false
```

---

I need to ignore the seconds and the milliseconds portion of these dates. I have tried to use the `withSecondOfMinute(0)` and `withMillis(0)` methods like the following.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
DateTime firstDate = formatter.parseDateTime("16-Feb-2012 12:03:45").withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillis(0);
DateTime secondDate = formatter.parseDateTime("17-Feb-2013 12:03:45").withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillis(0);
```

But it yielded the following output.

```
firstDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30
secondDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30
comparison = false

firstDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30
secondDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30
comparison = false

firstDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30
secondDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30
comparison = true
```

The docs of the `withSecondOfMinute()` method describes.

> Returns a copy of this datetime with the second of minute field
>   updated. DateTime is immutable, so there are no set methods. Instead,
>   this method returns a new instance with the value of second of minute
>   changed.

And the docs of the method `withMillis()` says.

> Returns a copy of this datetime with different millis. The returned
>   object will be either be a new instance or this. Only the millis will
>   change, the chronology and time zone are kept.

Comparing dates by ignoring the time portion completely can easily be done using [`DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#getDateOnlyInstance%28%29) roughly like the following.

```
if(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(firstDate, secondDate)==0){}
if(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(firstDate, secondDate)<0){}
if(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(firstDate, secondDate)>0){}
```

How to compare two dates ignoring the specific instant in `DateTime` (seconds and milliseconds in this case)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to use [`DateTime#withMillisOfSecond()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMillisOfSecond%28int%29) instead of [`DateTime#withMillis()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMillis%28long%29):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
DateTime firstDate = formatter.parseDateTime("16-Feb-2012 12:03:45").withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0);
DateTime secondDate = formatter.parseDateTime("17-Feb-2013 12:03:45").withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0);
```

Setting [`DateTime#withMillis()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMillis%28long%29) to `0`, will reset both your dates to `1/1/1970`, and hence you get `true` for `equals` call on them.

Similarly, setting [`DateTime#withMillisOfDay()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMillisOfDay%28int%29) to `0`, will set the time to `midnight`.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach is to create a DateTimeComparator with minute as lower limit:

```
DateTimeComparator comparator = DateTimeComparator.getInstance(
         DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour());
```

which would ignore the second and millisecond parts of the objects being compared.

Comment: I will try this approach later. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFromatDateTime(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime( date );
    //gc.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    //gc.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
    //block ignore second and millisecond
    gc.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
    gc.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(gc.getTime());
    return strDate;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date now = new  Date();
    String currentDate = Testing.getFromatDateTime(now);
    String fullDate = "2015-12-07 14:53:39.30";
    String effDateStr = Testing.getFromatDateTime(sdfDate.parse(fullDate));

    System.out.println("Currennt Date: " + currentDate);
    System.out.println("Effective Date: " + effDateStr);
    System.out.println(currentDate.compareTo(effDateStr)==0);
}
```